# communication b/w multiple clients with multithreading on client side and server side using sockets c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp, client-server

I have made a client and server program using sockets. On server side I have done multithreading so that each client is assigned a different thread. On client side, I want each client to be assigned a thread. For example, if there are 1000 clients that wants to communicate with the server then 1000 threads should be created, but here in my code I am getting an error "Error C2561   'receive': function must return a value". I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone just help me out?
And is this code correct? I mean am I doing the multithreading in a right way?

Answer (score 0):

```
DWORD WINAPI receive(LPVOID lpParam)
```

You declared this function as returning a `DWORD`.

```
return;
```

But here, you're not returning a value, as the error message explained to you. If you declare a function that returns some value, a `DWORD`, or anything else, then this is what you must return from the function, in every `return` statement. Change that `return` statement to return a `DWORD` value, and add one at the end of this function.

This function also ends without a `return` statement as well. That's also a problem that you must fix the same way. You need to figure out what your function should return, in every case, and change your code accordingly.

Comment: This error has been removed but now I am getting the error "Error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'clientsock' used". Can you please tell me if my code is correct or not?

Comment: This error message is also, pretty much, self-explanatory. It is true that C++ has a reputation for producing incomprehensible error message. But these ones are pretty clear and simpler. Can't think of any way to make "uninitialized local variable used" any more clear. The shown code declares `SOCKET clientsock;`, then passes object as a parameter to `CreateThread()` without initializing it to anything.